# GORM ORM: Preloading in both relationship directions possible?

Tags: database, go, orm, model, go-gorm

I would like to know if it is possible to preload data from both sides of a relationship. Consider this example:

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name      string
    Documents []Document // has-many
}
type Document struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID           uint
    Name             string
    DocumentFulltext DocumentFulltext // has-one
}
type DocumentFulltext struct {
    gorm.Model
    DocumentID uint
    Name       string
}
```

With that I can easily get the DocumentFulltext for any given document like this

```golang
db.Where("id = ?", ID).Preload("DocumentFulltext").Find(&document)
```

Works!

But what if I have the document and want to preload (or join) the User it belongs to?

```golang
db.Where("id = ?", ID).Preload("User").Find(&document)
```

That gives me a panic. (`invalid memory address`)

```golang
db.Where("id = ?", ID).Joins("User").Find(&document)
```

And that produces wonky SQL like `.... FROM "documents" User WHERE id = ...`

How is this possible? Do I need to use "manual" queries?

--

If it is not possible: what is a good-practice / guideline how to model my relationships so I can use GORM built-ins like .Preload() effectively?

E.g. If I put the relationship between Users and Documents like this:

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}
type Document struct {
    gorm.Model
    User             User // belongs-to
    UserID           uint
    Name             string
    DocumentFulltext DocumentFulltext // has-one
}
type DocumentFulltext struct {
    gorm.Model
    DocumentID uint
    Name       string
}
```

then I can preload both, DocumentFulltext AND User, for any given Document. But I loose the ability the preload Documents and Fulltexts if I want to do it for a given User.

--

Any hints a re appreciated. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relation both side means `User` in `Document` struct and `Documents` in `User` struct

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name      string
    Documents []Document // has-many
}

type Document struct {
    gorm.Model
    UseredID uint
    Name     string
    User   User
}
```

Then you can preload both sides

```
db.Debug().Where("id = ?", ID).Preload("User").Find(&document)
db.Debug().Where("id = ?", ID).Preload("Documents").Find(&user)
```